# Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int' using Asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am creating a simple crud system using asp.net mvc.  when i enter the record and click add button this error displayed.

I get the error on this line:  `if (rec.id > 0)`

> (parameter)product rec
>
> operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'**

Code which i tried

**sales controller**

```
 public ActionResult save(product rec)
    {
        bool status = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (aspposEntities1 db = new aspposEntities1())
            {
                if (rec.id > 0) // this line i got the error
                {
                    var v = db.products.Where(a => a.id == rec.id).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {
                        v.proname = rec.proname;
                        v.cat_id = rec.cat_id;
                        v.brand_id = rec.brand_id;
                        v.qty = rec.qty;
                        v.price = rec.price;
                        db.Entry(v).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    db.products.Add(rec);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    }
```

**product class**
**product.cs**

```
public partial class product
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string proname { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> cat_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> brand_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> qty { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: id is a string, you are comparing it to an integer. You can't compare a string directly to an int in c#. Is the id of a product supposed to be numeric?

Comment: If `id` is supposed to be a string then do `if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(rec.id))` to check if it is set.

Comment: if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(rec.id))  i got the error string does not contain the defination of if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(rec.id))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rec.Id` Type is String.

you should convert `rec.Id` to int or long

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you exactly what the problem is.  Your `id` property is a string, and you are comparing it to `0`, an integer.

Options:

- `if(Convert.ToInt32(rec.id) > 0`  (But remember null checks)
- Change `id` to be an `int` (Preferred option)

[Further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/).

Comment: sir i cannot change the id to be int because i have generating E001 like id generered.i i tried the code above sir i got the differnt error An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: That `Convert.ToInt32()` call is going to fail badly once out in production, since id is likely external input.

Comment: @TanveerBadar That's why it should never have been a `string` in the first place.  Who knows what data sanitisation has been done?

Comment: @jayapriya If the `id` is not actually just a number like you suggest (E001), then you can't compare it to `0`.

Comment: @Moo-Juice None is my guess. Given the responses by OP, I am assuming a profound lack of understanding what mine field she stepped into.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are unable to change the `id` property to be an `int`, here's one way to check for valid IDs.

`if(int.TryParse(rec.id, out var id) && id > 0)`

Comment: Likely your language version is something ancient.